# Why isn't Error's stack property included in Object.keys?

Tags: javascript

env: nodejs 8.1.5, also tested on jscomplete with same results

```
const error = new Error("message");
const { message, ...rest } = error;
const keys = Object.keys(error);
const hasStack = error.hasOwnProperty("stack");
```

The rest object turns out to not include the stack property because Object.keys does not return it and a "for in" will not pick it up.
It is, however, an own property of the error object (hasStack is true above).

What gives? I couldn't find anything about special-casing this property in the documentation or the polyfill on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: `stack` is on `Error.prototype` and it is non-enumerable. The same reason you don't get `push` if you use `for...in` on an array

Comment: Some of the error properties like `lineno`, `colno`, `error` (for a *normal* thrown error, they don't look present on a `new Error`) are getters on the prototype, but the `message` and the `stack` aren't, they're directly on the error object

Comment: The typescript implementation tslib of ...rest uses for in so it won’t destructure non enumerable props. Good to know

Answer (score 4):

It's not enumerable, so it won't be included in `Object.keys` or a `for..in` iteration:

```js
const error = new Error("message");
// For Chrome, it's directly on the object:
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(error, 'stack'));
// For Firefox, it's a getter on the prototype:
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(error), 'stack'));
```

To iterate over *all* properties, including non-enumerable ones, use `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` instead:

```js
// Chrome:
const error = new Error("message");
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error).forEach((propName) => {
  console.log(propName);
});
```

On Firefox, those two properties are getters on the prototype, rather than being directly on the `error` object. (The prototype also has other properties other than `stack` and `message`)

```js
// Chrome:
const error = new Error("message");
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(error)).forEach((propName) => {
  console.log(propName);
});
```